# Consider $n$ numbers $a_1,..., a_n$ and $x_1,..., x_n$. Can one find a polynomial, $f(x)\in R[x]$ st $f$ path through $(x_i,a_i) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider $n$ arbitrary integer numbers $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ and real numbers $x_1,\ldots, x_n$. Can one find a polynomial, $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that the graph of $f$ path through $(x_1,a_1), \cdots , (x_n,a_n) $, and

1. $\deg(f)=n$
2. $\deg(f)=n-1$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To get you started: if for example $n=3$ we can construct the following polynomial passing through the three points $(x_i,a_i)$:

$$f(x) = a_1 + \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_3)}{(x_2-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}[a_2-a_1] + \frac{(x-x_1)(x-x_2)}{(x_3-x_1)(x_3-x_2)}[a_3-a_1]$$ This construction can be generalized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the $x_i$'s are distinct.

Step 1: For any $i$, can you find a polynomial which vanishes at $x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n$?  (And does not vanish at $x_i$).

Step 2: For any $i$, can you take the polynomial discovered in Step 1 and make its value $a_i$ at $x_i$ (and the value $0$ at $x_j$ for $j\not=i$).

Step 3: Can you combine such polynomials (for all $i$) into a solution?

Comment: The polynomials constructed here are the [Lagrange polynomials](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)

Answer (score 2):

For degree $n$, it can be done, using a construction along the lines described in the answer by Michael Burr. One needs a little trick to ensure the degree is exactly $n$.

For degree $n-1$, in general it cannot be done. The Lagrange interpolation process produces a polynomial of degree $\le n-1$, but finding a polynomial of degree *exactly* $n-1$ is not always possible.

For example, let $a_i=0$ for all $i$. Suppose there is a polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n-1$ such that $P(x_i)=a_i$ for all $i$. This polynomial vanishes at $n$ places, so must be the zero polynomial. Alternately, we can use $a_i=x_i$.